# Relation between laplacian matrix and incidence matrix for an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

On [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) I found the relation:

$$L={M^T}M$$

for the laplacian matrix $L$ in terms of the incidence matrix $M$ for a directed graph.

But what about an undirected graph?

Comment: An undirected graph is just a special case of a directed graph; specifically, one where node $i$ points to node $j$ if and only if node $j$ also points to node $i$. So $L=M^T M$ also holds for undirected graphs.

Comment: If it is undirected then it ($M$) shall be symmetric already without need to do $M^TM$.

Comment: @Semiclassical are you sure? For what I know, an incidence matrix of an undirected graph has entries $0$ or $1$, not $1$ and $-1$, while if you look at the example section on the linked Wikipedia page the laplacian matrix there has negative entries.